# How to replace all contiguous uppercase letters with a single underscore in Python

Tags: python, regex

For example

"JHDKFksdKSJDsGGGG" becomes "_ksd_s_"

Is there a way to replace uppercase-clusters with a single underscore?

Comment: What have you tried? If you can't get started on this yourself it might be a good idea to avoid regex. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re` module:

```
import re
s = 'JHDKFksdKSJDsGGGG'
print re.sub('[A-Z]+','_',s)
```

Basically, what it does is it replaces uppercase clusters  (the `[A-Z]+` part) with underscore (the second argument).

`[A-Z]` matches any uppercase character from `A` to `Z` and the `+` means you want to have a match with at least one character (you don't want to replace empty string with underscore).

So together, `[A-Z]+` matches a cluster of uppercase letters.

So what `re.sub` does is that it takes in 3 parameters (pattern, replacement, and string).  It goes through the string, looking for something that matches the pattern (in this case: looks like a group of uppercase characters), and replaces these groups with the replacement string.

Comment: What does each piece of this mean?

Comment: [A-Z] doesn't match a cluster or group. It's a character class that matches a *single* character in the A-Z range, i.e. any capital letter. It's the **+** that makes it a "cluster" (match one or more of the preceding character or class).

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("[A-Z]+", "_", "JHDKFksdKSJDsGGGG")
'_ksd_s_'
```

`[A-Z]` means match any characters in the range A-Z inclusive.
`+` means match one or more of the previous expression.

Answer (score 1):

The obligatory non-regex solution:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = "JHDKFksdKSJDsGGGG"
>>> ''.join('_' if k else ''.join(g) for k,g in groupby(s, str.isupper))
'_ksd_s_'
```

`groupby` groups contiguous elements of an iterable together if they have the same value, in this case specified by the keyfunction `str.isupper`.  IOW, `groupby` produces

```
>>> [(k, list(g)) for k,g in groupby(s, str.isupper)]
[(True, ['J', 'H', 'D', 'K', 'F']), (False, ['k', 's', 'd']), 
(True, ['K', 'S', 'J', 'D']), (False, ['s']), (True, ['G', 'G', 'G', 'G'])]
```

and then we replace or leave alone accordingly.